# CSS slider adjust the box

Tags: html, css, slider

how do I make the box smaller? i cant seem to make it smaller tried adding width it goes small but the other box show up and it mess up the slider[this is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boGrV.png)
[my css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU9iC.png)

I just want it to make it smaller that display it in the middle and doesn't mess up when i also change into mobile mode

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.